# Learning terminal by observing commands being run by GUI

Tags: command-line, scripts, source-code, xprop

Hello I'm new to the Linux system and would like to know if there is a code or application which opens a terminal that will tell me the lines of code being used.  For example, If I were to open a folder or directory I would like to know the lines of code associated with it.

Comment: When an application is compiled successfully, references to the original source are lost. An expert could install the -dbg (debug) version of the software to get information about exactly what is going oin under the hood, but I would not recommend that to a beginner. Most folks simply don't learn how Linux works this particular way.

Answer (score 11):

If you think whatever you do in your GUI has a terminal (CLI shell: bash, csh, ...) command associated with, and for example when using your file manager you go into a directory named `foo`, behind the seen something like `$ cd foo` would happen then you are wrong.

The GUI is a shell itself just like your CLI shell (say bash).
Both GUI and CLI use some kind of programming interface to talk to the kernel for handling your requests. Each have their own implementation and work their own way.

However, there is a high chance that whatever you do in GUI has an equivalent command in CLI. For knowing these commands you should read manuals, documentation and start working with CLI.